# std::result_of doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, result-of

I'm trying to use `std::result_of` to determine the return type of a callable object:

```
template <typename T>
std::result_of<T()>::type CallableWrapper(T callableObj) {
    return callableObj();
}
```

Somewhere else in the code:

```
auto i = CallableWrapper([](){return 1;});
```

This code doesn't compile for some reason. I will appreciate if someone would tell me why.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: you are missing a `typename` keyword in front of `std::result_of`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks! This works perfectly. Why is the extra `typename` required?

Comment: @user because `type` is a nested type that depends on `T`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with trailing return type and `decltype`, like

```
template<typename T>
auto CallableWrapper(T callableObj) -> decltype(std::declval<T>()())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know this is possible, I was just wondering what I'm missing in the code above.